Format date output with spaces into awk
I want to make the date command with nice formatting like this:
awk -F, '{system("date -d " $1 " +%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")}' file.log

However it does not work
Try 'date --help' for more information.
date: extra operand ‘%H:%M’

What is correct way to do this, so that date command to get one correct argument?
Why it fails when I put an space between "year" and "hour"?
Thanks in advance

If you ran that outside of awk/system, e.g. date -d today +%d/%m/%Y %H:%M, you'd get the same error so debug calling date on it's own first and then call it the same way from inside awk. If you need quotes on the command line (you do) then you need quotes inside the string you're passing to awk/system.

Calling an external command from awk will be very slow - you might want to consider not doing that. In particular GNU awk has it's own time functions so you may not need to call date from awk at all.

Depending on your OS and the original timestamp format, you might be able to use ts (from moreutils) to reformat the timestamps e.g. ts -r '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M' < file.log

This has nothing to do with awk:
$ date -d  today  +%d/%m/%Y %H:%M
date: extra operand ‘%H:%M’
Try 'date --help' for more information.

The date command takes one argument, but you are giving it two: +%d/%m/%Y and %H:%M. The shell splits arguments on whitespace, so if you want that to be treated as a single argument, you need to quote it:
$ date -d  today  "+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
19/07/2024 11:14

So to get your awk command to work, you could do:
$ awk -F, '{system("date -d " $1 " \"+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M\"")}' file.log
19/07/2024 11:15

Or, alternatively, escape the space:
$ awk -F, '{system("date -d " $1 " +%d/%m/%Y\\ %H:%M")}' file.log
19/07/2024 19:30

Of the two, I prefer the quoting since that is also what you should do in the shell itself, so is a good habit to get into. Both should work fine here though.
You probably don't need this though. Since you're using date -d, you're probably on a GNU system and have GNU awk (gawk), so you can use its own date functions. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html#Time-Functions.

very thanks! That's it

Escaping the space with \\  should also do it.

Thanks, @kaz, added.

That's going to result in nasal demons depending on the contents of the input file. environment variable settings, the directory you call it from, etc. since it's passing the contents of $1 to the shell unquoted. If you were to call date directly from the shell with literal strings as arguments you should enclose them in single quotes, i.e. date -d 'today' '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M' so you should do the same when calling the shell from awk to execute a command with literal strings, i.e. it should be system("date -d \047" $1 "\047 \047+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M\047")
